# adding a contrib dependency to simpletest

Tags: 8, testing

Is it possible? I am trying to contribute to a drupal module (first time) and I have uploaded a patch.

But the test keeps failing because of an unmet dependency on the libraries API. I have added the dependency to the $modules static in the simpletest but now I get an error:

fail: [Other] Line 33 of modules/swiftmailer/src/Tests/SwiftMailerSettingsTest.php:
Unable to install modules libraries, swiftmailer, block due to missing modules libraries.

I'm getting really frustrated because I can't figure out how to fix it. D8 documentation is just not sufficient...

I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could help me out because I'm about ready to give up.

The issue page I created is here https://www.drupal.org/node/2620822 And this is the test code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\swiftmailer\Tests\SwiftMailerSettingsTest.
 */

 namespace Drupal\swiftmailer\Tests;

 use Drupal\simpletest\WebTestBase;

/**
 * Tests the Transport and Message Settings UI.
 *
 * @group swiftmailer
 */
class SwiftMailerSettingsTest extends WebTestBase {

  /**
   * Modules to enable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  public static $modules = [
    'libraries',
    'swiftmailer',
    'block',
  ];

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();
  $this->drupalPlaceBlock('local_tasks_block');
    $this->drupalPlaceBlock('local_actions_block');
  }

  /**
   * Tests the Transport Settings.
   */
  public function testTransportSettings() {
// Unauthorized user should not have access.
$this->drupalGet('admin/config/swiftmailer/transport');
$this->assertResponse(403);

// Login..
$user = $this->createUser(['administer swiftmailer']);
$this->drupalLogin($user);
$this->drupalGet(t('admin/config/swiftmailer/transport'));
$this->assertText(t('Transport types'));

//Select Smtp tranport option.
$this->drupalPostAjaxForm(NULL, [ 'transport[type]' => 'smtp' ], ['transport[type]' => 'smtp']);
$this->drupalPostForm(NULL, [
  'transport[type]' => 'smtp',
  'transport[configuration][smtp][username]' => 'example',
  'transport[configuration][smtp][password]' => 'pass'
], t('Save configuration'));
$this->assertText('using the SMTP transport type.');

//Loading configuration to check if is set up correctly.
$config = $this->config('swiftmailer.transport');
$transport = $config->get('transport');
$user= $config->get('smtp_username');
$password= $config->get('smtp_password');
$this->assertEqual($transport, 'smtp');
$this->assertEqual($user, 'example');
$this->assertEqual($password, 'pass');

//Select Sppol tranport option.
$this->drupalPostAjaxForm(NULL, [ 'transport[type]' => 'spool' ], ['transport[type]' => 'spool']);
$this->drupalPostForm(NULL, [
  'transport[type]' => 'spool',
  'transport[configuration][spool][directory]' => 'aaaaa'
], t('Save configuration'));
$this->assertText('using the Spool transport type.');

//Loading configuration to check if is set up correctly.
$config = $this->config('swiftmailer.transport');
$transport = $config->get('transport');
$directory = $config->get('spool_directory');
$this->assertEqual($transport, 'spool');
$this->assertEqual($directory, 'aaaaa');

//Select Sendmail tranport option.
$this->drupalPostAjaxForm(NULL, [ 'transport[type]' => 'sendmail' ], ['transport[type]' => 'sendmail']);
$this->drupalPostForm(NULL, [
  'transport[type]' => 'sendmail',
  'transport[configuration][sendmail][path]' => 'bbbbb'
    ], t('Save configuration'));
    $this->assertText('using the Sendmail transport type.');

    //Loading configuration to check if is set up correctly.
    $config = $this->config('swiftmailer.transport');
    $transport = $config->get('transport');
    $path = $config->get('sendmail_path');
    $this->assertEqual($transport, 'sendmail');
    $this->assertEqual($path, 'bbbbb');
  }

  public function testMessageSettings() {
    $this->drupalGet('admin/config/swiftmailer/transport');
    $this->assertResponse(403);

    // Login..
    $user = $this->createUser(['administer swiftmailer']);
    $this->drupalLogin($user);
    $this->drupalGet(t('admin/config/swiftmailer/transport'));
    $this->assertText(t('Transport types'));

    $this->clickLink('Messages');
    $this->assertText(t('Message format'));

    $this->drupalPostForm(NULL, [
      'format[type]' => 'text/html',
      'convert[mode]' => 'TRUE',
      'character_set[type]' => 'EUC-CN'
    ], t('Save configuration'));
    $this->assertText('The configuration options have been saved.');

    $config = $this->config('swiftmailer.message');
    $format = $config->get('format');
    $mode = $config->get('convert_mode');
    $character = $config->get('character_set');
    $this->assertEqual($format, 'text/html');
    $this->assertEqual($mode, 'TRUE');
    $this->assertEqual($character, 'EUC-CN');
  }
}`
```

So things seem to be going wrong during the setup process: i want to enable the contrib module libraries becaues the module depends on that. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Does the test fail because there aren't library files? Seeing the code would help.

Comment: Also, knowing the module or the issue in question sure would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need libraries module for swiftmailer?

Swiftmailer dependencies in 8.x-1.x are installed using composer (manager). Which is something that the testbot currently simply does not support.

That said, the generic answer:

Adding the dependency to the test is not enough, it also needs to be 
specified in the info.yml file as test_dependencies entry. That however only works when already committed. So if you try to do that, you need two patches/issues. First add the dependencies, wait a while until dependencies are rebuilt and then provide the rest of the patch.